# Unable to access GCP service after gke upgrade

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform

Automatic upgrade in mid-May.

```
1.14.10-gke.27 → 1.14.10-gke.36
```

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-notes?_ga=2.196679278.-315187236.1572486593#may_13_2020

After that, I got Memorystore（Redis）connection error and crul6 error.

crul error

```
cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: www.googleapis.com (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

This problem happens occasionally, not always.
It worked fine before the upgrade.

- Role-based access control not use
- Workload Identity not use

Please advise.

Comment: That error means that your DNS PODS may not be quite stable. Are you using preemptible nodes? Also, can you please verify if the DNS PODS are up and running without restarts?

Comment: Could you share whole error message? Have you tried steps mentioned [here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48212316/google-api-php-client-curl-error-6-could-not-resolve-host/48562350#48562350). Does `/etc/hosts` file contain proper hostname?

Comment: @ArmandoCuevas Thanks for your comment.
The node has preemptible enabled.
When I ran the availability policy test, I was able to reproduce the redis connection error and the curl6 error. `gcloud compute instances simulate-maintenance-event <instance name> --zone <zone>` Let's disable pretentive and see what happens. I want to select your comment as the best answer, so please rewrite it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close it once.
Probably not a gke version issue.

The reason is that the node was a preemptible node.
That is likely.

When I ran the reboot test of the Pretentive Node, I was able to reproduce the error.

```
gcloud compute instances simulate-maintenance-event <instance name> --zone <zone>
```